# MVC ClientSide Validation Events

Tags: model-view-controller, events, validation, client-side

Does anyone know if there is an event which is fired off on success of the client side validation and how I would go about using this.

I have enabled it but I need to run some script onSuccess.

```
 <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and attach a function to the submit of the form

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
 //You can use event.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting on it's own
 if($(this).valid())
  { //Do something } 
 else 
  {  } 
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/